How to approach cutting stock problem that minimises waste and calculates the number of borads to use for cutting
I am trying to develop an algorithm for two dimensional cutting stock problem, but it should also be able to calculate the number of boards to cut from. Here is an example:

Base boards are all the same size, for example 200x100.
I want to cut some pieces from those boards, always in rectangular shape, without preference in orientation:

3 boards 20x30
1 board 40x40
2 boards 100x20

I want the output to be the minimal number of base boards used to cut those pieces from, which includes optimising cutting to minimize waste.

Do you have any tips and aproaches to this problem, or code examples that work on something similar?
I wanted to try to implement genetic algorithm for 2D cutting stock problem to minimise waste, but the N base boards part is what I don't know how to handle.

Asking for "any tips and approaches... or code examples that work on something similar" is off topic on Stack Overflow. Please check out How to Ask a good question, and take the tour.

"but the N base boards part is what I don't know how to handle." << I suggest running a greedy algorithm to get a first solution. This first solution is not necessarily optimal, but the number of boards N0 used in this first solution is an upper-bound on the number of boards of the optimal solution, so then you can run your genetic algorithm considering N0 boards (some of which may remain unused in better solutions). This way the number of boards is "constant" in some sense.
